# Noob in kotlin. I need help on Imageview

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I would like to ask you a question from a guy who have just started programming in kotlin.
I want to change an image of an app and to do so I want to use the Imageview.setImageResource but it's like the setImageResource atribute it's not detected. Any idea of what can it be? Maybe I lack a library or something? Thank you!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXm8I.png)

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots, add it as a code block so it's searchable.

Answer (score 1):

`setImageResource()` isn't a static method of the ImageView class so you can't call it directly via the class name. You'll need to call it on an instance of an ImageView like so :

```
val myImage : ImageView = findViewByID(R.id.yourID)
myImage.setImageResource(YOUR_RESOURCE)
```

P.S: Please next time, instead of posting a screenshot of your code, post your actual code so people can help you better.

Comment: Also, if this answered your question please consider marking it as the selected answer.